# How to open a document in an Excel Sheet using Xpath?

Tags: excel, testing, xpath

Using my testing program I get an RAW Excel Output.

It's template utilizes xpath to fill its values.

In one cell, I use the xpath to get a specific file location value.

**Is there a way for me to open that file location value?**

**NOTE: Hyperlinks aren't working since the testing program produces raw excel files.**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "RAW Excel Output" ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I mean to say that the data that is being placed in the excel is raw data. Which if I apply a hyperlink, it won't work because the data changes every time an output is produced.

Comment: Have you tried using a `HYPERLINK()` formula in the output?

Comment: How should it be written? HYPERLINK(--file location--)?

Comment: I get the raw data yung Xpath. so should my syntax in the cell be like..

=HYPERLINK([[xpath-query]]) ??

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're doing or what you want to change.  How are you currently using Xpath?